# iDRAC 9: RACADM how to view pdisks in a vdisk

Tags: server, automation, system-administration

Currently I'm trying to find a way to location which physical disks are in each virtual disk. In the web iDRAC it has an option to view physical disks but I can't find it in the cli version.

I know I can use:

racadm storage get vdisks -o

racadm storage get pdisks -o

to get the status of each but I haven't been able to find a way to link the information together. Has anyone been able to successfully do this? I've read the racadm guide completely and I wasn't able to find anything besides how to create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find it

racadm storage get pdisks -vdkey:VD FQDD